# How to set a default file as the first file to run in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a project with one main function in the `my_main.py` file and this file is using many other files I have created. Is there a way to tell vs code to always run `my_main.py` each time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> regardless of the file that I am currently working on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a launch configuration in `launch.json` that looks something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

You can simply change the `"program"` to `"${workspaceFolder}/my_main.py"`.

Comment: Thanks! This is working but is there a more generic way so it will work with all of my projects? If it can look for the `main()` function in the current workspace.

Comment: I don't think so. Besides, you'd need a separate `launch.json` for those projects anyway?

Comment: I don’t think that I understand you. Where is the ’launch.Jason’ file? Is it unique for each project / workspace?

Comment: Usually yes, although it is possible to have "global" launch configurations as well. See the official docs for more details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations